# Babel Path Transpilation to absolute Path

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am encountering very weird behavior of babel path transpilation. in my project some modules are called as following

```
import module from '~modulename'
```

where ~ means import given 'modulename' from root of project directory. now how this works fine for dev (babel-node for running project). but when i run `babel src -d lib` on my project for transpiling es6 js everything is converted (trans piled) but this path doesn't so in build i am always left with `require('~modulename')` instead `require('../../...modulename')`.

Solutions i have tried

1. aliasing ~ to ./ in babel.config.js through module-resolver-plugin

Babel.config.js

```
module.exports = __babel => {
  // Use cache.
  __babel.cache(true)

  // Return configuration.
  return {
    'presets': [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          'modules': false
        }
      ]
    ],
    'plugins': [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
      'dynamic-import-node',
      'babel-plugin-root-import',
      ['babel-plugin-module-resolver', { 'alias': { '~': './' } }]
      ['module-resolver', { 'root': ['./', 'packages/*'] }],
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', { 'allowTopLevelThis': true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { 'regenerator': true }]
    ],
    'env': {
      'production': {
        'presets': ['minify'],
        'plugins': [
          'transform-remove-console',
          'minify-dead-code-elimination'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably not a solution, but `./` is the current folder, the root folder is `/`.

Comment: @Teemu that make no difference either. still you are left with '~modulename'